# In it for the long haul

Tags: phrase-meaning, collocation

I need your help with this collocation. The context:

> Warren Buffett is not looking to make any kind of quick turn around on his investment. **In it for the long haul**, Buffett will hold stocks for 5 or 10 years before thinking about selling them - that is, he employs the "buy and hold" strategy as well.

To my guess in means "In order to get more from his investment in the long run", Buffet will hold stocks for 5-10 years <...> 
Am i right?

Thanks to all.

Comment: *Be in something for the long haul* has its own [entry in ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/long_haul).

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty much right. Literally, "long-haul" refers to

> travelling a long distance ([*Cambridge Online*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/long-haul))

This gave birth to the idiomatic "the long haul" meaning

> a period of years, rather than days, weeks, or months ([*Cambridge Online*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/long-haul))

So in this context, it does indeed mean that Buffett is willing to hold his stocks for a long period in order to get more from his investment overall rather than making a quick profit.